# Why does Chrome block opening new tab while redirecting?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a react app with a specific link. When a user clicks on the link, it opens a new tab, also it redirects the current page to the home page. This is what I am doing in the `handleClick` function:

```
window.location.href = '/';
const win = window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');
win.focus();
```

But when I do this, Chrome blocks the popup. Since the redirect also happens, the popup blocked message also disappears. But the interesting part is, it works when I change the order, like this:

```
const win = window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');
window.location.href = '/';
win.focus();
```

Any idea why this happens? I went through the docs, but couldn't find any. I just want to ensure that the second method works all the time, and Chrome will not stop blocking that in the future.

To quickly try this out, you can execute the following two lines in Chrome console in both order:

```
window.location.href = 'https://yahoo.com';
window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 4):

When you put `window.location.href = '/';` before `window.open`, the browser is already loading the new requested page, and unloading the current page, hence any script statements after that statement may or may not run. That could be the cause you are getting the popup.

However in the second case `window.open` runs first normally just like any other JS statement and then the redirect triggers.

Comment: Do you think that is causing the popup blocked message?